# How are we doing in this Private Beta?

Tags: discussion, statistics

We're a week since Stack Exchange Area 51 announced invitation for Worldbuilding private beta for all of us and we [currently have <s>93</s> 94 questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions). How we're doing? Is it good, poor or critically low?

This is my first SE site, where I participate in private beta. My journey with most others started at public beta. Though my commitment to these sites started many days, weeks or even months after starting public beta, I must admit, that I find it quite nervous for me personally to see, that those public beta sites had  thousands of questions (4-6k), while our site has less than a hundred.

As I said, I have completely no idea / information / experience, how this should look in private beta, so I might mess some things out. But, I must admit, that each time I'm looking at these *poor* <s>93</s> 94 questions, I fear really much, that we're doing really, really bad, and that there will be no public beta at all.

I would apperciate, if someone with experience could spoke and say, that I see these things in a very bad way, and that we're doing really good. I think, my following nights would be much peaceful, after this...

Comment: Those public beta sites have been open for a year or more.  ~100 questions in our first week is not bad.  Though ill admit its less than I had hoped for.

Comment: We're only just entering our 6th day, and we now have 105 questions. Also the dip over the weekend seems to have been temporary - the questions are coming in quicker today. We need to keep working as hard as we can and define the scope of the site, but I think we are making excellent progress.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. It seems, we're doing very good. The only problem are visits. And the question, if we're going to attract enough people / visits during public beta?

Comment: @trejder 150 visits per day for a private beta with less than 200 users total doesn't seem bad at all to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm Grace Note, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. And one of these days I'll get to make an announcement for you guys as a question rather than an answer.

Statistically, this site's doing great. We're very happy with what we're seeing. The volume's doing decently, the breadth of coverage is also nice, and most of all the community here is doing astoundingly well. The one major thing the site has going for it is that the people who've committed here are committed to taking it seriously. Y'all are questioning everything about your process and trying to make sure things work, not by trying to force things in, but by working with the system and with each other. The amount of Meta discussion here is very nice to see. All in all, the performance of this site is healthy and full of all the things we love to look for in the private beta.

**We're planning to hold the site back for one more week of private beta**. Right now, there's still some pretty active discussion about certain matters such as the importance of evidence and "backing-it-up", and how best to manage this in a way that avoids sacrificing either creativity or rigid usefulness. It's a tough nut to crack and we think it'll suit the site better to have some more time to focus on that material before opening to the public at large.  Once the community's at least got more solid ground on content policies, next week we should be able to hit public launch for everyone.

Comment: Hi Grace, any chance we can get an update? Especially on the pro tem moderator situation as we are starting to get traffic that could use moderation... Thanks :)

Comment: "one of these days"... it makes me inexplicably proud of what Stack Exchange can achieve that *one of these days* has happened and we're past that milestone, too.

Answer (score 8):

I have been with 3 sites from private to public (and very active in 2 of them (one being the most active non-mod review queue processor, the other being a protem moderator)).

Our quality, number of questions and number of answers are all **very** good for a private beta. No question the public beta will be very soon.

Answer (score 5):

if you go back to the Area51 and look at the world building, it give you a sort of score card.  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding  We're not doing to bad according to that.

Comment: Though those statistics assume public beta.

Comment: yep, so considering we haven't gotten there yet, I don't think it's too bad.

Comment: @bowlturner - I agree. All the stats about questions (rather than visits/usage) are great.  And the visits/usage stats are irrelevant because we're in *private* beta, so there's no way to attract more users yet.