# The focus for our next week

Tags: discussion

Now that it has been [decided to give us a second week](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/177/109) to clarify our content policies, what do you most want to see clarified? Obviously we will continue to ask and answer things as they come up, on main and meta, but for anyone with some spare time but uncertain where to focus their effort, what would be most useful?

Is there anything already being discussed that could benefit from more example questions on the border between good fit and bad fit to try and test what works and what doesn't? Although we have excellent meta participation, there is still slightly more feedback available in the main site that on the meta site, so asking main site questions is a good way to find out what the community approves of.

What do you want to see discussed and explored and better defined?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to see how much detail we expect from questioners.  If the question is about how magic would effect x or how ftl travel would work/effect shipping lanes and culture, how much detail do we want on the particular magical system/ftl travel physics before we answer?

If there are multiple possible ways a question could play out, should we give a listy type answer or ask for clarification/vote to close as unclear?

Also, nailing down too broad vs too specific would be good.  Questions can easily swing one way or the other.

Comment: in combo with that - how about a **TLNR** guideline? So some of the very long answers could be specific but also short

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it we should use the time to make the Questions and answers a bit more polished.

I for my part will go back to my posts and look over them. So when public Beta starts their will be lots of wrong grammar and German influenced sentences but it will look goooood.

Also we should upvote some more i think - most of the questions dont even have half of the active user votes.

Comment: Don't upvote for the sake of it, upvote if something is impressive/interesting/whatever to you :)

Comment: I do... just now i go to aaaaaall the questions and answers and reread them. I was pointing at the fact that the majorety of the questions have about 50 views, what isnt quite much or isnt it?

Comment: Considering that the beta has only 200 people that means a quarter of the people have viewed each question...that's pretty good really I think.

Comment: oh that are individual views? i thought that this was the overall views counter.

Comment: We do need to make sure that we go back through questions that have fallen off the front page and make sure they are answered.

Comment: Our unanswered questions number hovers around zero. There's a link from the questions page to view just unanswered questions. It shows you those without a sufficiently upvoted answer.